# BC30201: Expression expected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The following line of code gives the above error when the aspx code is run under IIS on my local machine.

```
Details = If(.GetString(2) = "", "", "<div><b>" & .GetString(2) & "</b></div>")
```

The exact same code runs without error on the production web server.
I have just taken over looking after this site and I have not come across this type of If statement before.

Here is the code that preceeds the statement above which produces the BC30201 error.

```
' Execute SQL procedure to fetch performance details

With New SQLCommand("FetchPerformance1", New SQLConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("C1").ConnectionString))

.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Performance", Code)
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Filters",     Convert.ToByte(Mid(Query, 24, 1), 16))

.CommandType = StoredProcedure : .Connection.Open

With .ExecuteReader(CloseConnection)


' If performance not found ...

If Not .Read


' Display message page:




' Terminate script:

    .Close : Response.End

End If


' Construct performance details string:

If .GetInt32(0) > 0 Then  Links  = "<a href=""view3.aspx" & Left(Query, 24) & Hex(.GetInt32(0)) & """ style=""float:  left"">&lt;&lt;</a>"
If .GetInt32(1) > 0 Then  Links &= "<a href=""view3.aspx" & Left(Query, 24) & Hex(.GetInt32(1)) & """ style=""float: right"">&gt;&gt;</a>"
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?
The syntax looks very weird. Dot operator (`.`) means you are accessing a method of an object, but there is nothing before the dot. Also, if means there should be decision between `true` and `false` and there is no such thing here

Comment: BC30201: Expression expected is the error that I get. The Dot operator (.) refers to the third field of a record.  My second question was that I did not fully understand what the if statement was trying to achieve.

Comment: I think we will need more than just one line. Give us some code surrounding it. Also which language are we looking at?

Comment: The language is VB, I will add more code when I get back tonight.

Comment: Code prior to the failing statement added as requested

Comment: The error message from my local IIS server shows its version as Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491  while the production server that the code runs on ok is at Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36373. I am currently trying to upgrade my machine to Version 4 but I am having problems so have raised a separate question

Comment: Changed to ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319 works fine

Answer (score 0):

Configured IIS to use ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36373. and it works fine

Comment: And the reason is that the `If` operator is not supported in VB in .Net version 2.0